# Redshift duplicate records

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am loading CSV files to Redshift. I first run the `COPY` command to a staging table, then normalize the account data into a separate lookup table.

```sql
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO AccountLookup (Account)
    SELECT DISTINCT Account FROM Staging db
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AccountLookup acct WHERE acct.Account = db.Account);
END;
```

I expect the above query to not insert any duplicate rows into the `AccountLookup` table. It works most of the time. But I rarely do find some duplicate entries which is causing some problems.

Next, I am using the following query to transfer the data from staging table to main table. Here I perform join on the lookup table to get the account id. Since the lookup table has duplicate entries, the main table also gets duplicate entries which it shouldn't have.

```sql
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Main (Usage, AccountId, Cost)
    SELECT bd.Usage, acct.Id, bd.Cost FROM Staging bd
    LEFT JOIN AccountLookup acct ON bd.Account = acct.Account;
END;
```

I can eliminate duplicates in the Main table by using the `row_number()` window function. But I would like to avoid inserting duplicate entries in the lookup table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Main (Usage, AccountId, Cost)
    SELECT bd.Usage, acct.Id, bd.Cost FROM Staging bd
    LEFT JOIN AccountLookup acct ON bd.Account = acct.Account
    GROUP BY bd.Usage, acct.Id, bd.Cost;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only `INSERT` `DISTINCT` rows, that are not in the main TABLE, which you can ensure with [EXISTS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/redshift/latest/dg/r_exists_condition.html)

You should alos do that for the first query

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Main (Usage, AccountId, Cost)
    SELECT DISTINCT bd.Usage, acct.Id, bd.Cost FROM Staging bd
    LEFT JOIN AccountLookup acct ON bd.Account = acct.Account
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Main  
        WHERE main.Usage = bd.Usage AND main.AccountId = acct.Id 
         AND main.Cost =  bd.Cost);
END;
```